# Stumped by a notation.

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

I'm reading through http://cr.yp.to/papers/primesieves.pdf and came across the following notation on p. 1:

> For example, a squarefree positive integer $p \in 1 + 4\Bbb Z$ is prime if and only if the equation $4x^2 + y^2 = p$ has an odd number of positive solutions $(x,y)$.

What I'm confused about is the use of the blackboard bold expression $1+4\Bbb Z$ as a restriction on the $p$ variable. I've seen field theorists use stuff like $p \in {\Bbb Z}/12{\Bbb Z}$ for a finite field element, but this one is new to me.

Comment: It just means integers of the form $4x+1$.

Comment: Um, have you really seen $\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z12$ anywhere, and not $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$?

Comment: And has anybody really claimed that $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ (or $\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z12$) is a field?

Comment: The $12{\Bbb Z}$ was a typo. @AndreasBlass maybe you should learn how to read. Do you know the difference between an object itself and an element of that object? Let's say you had a field formed from some polynomials with their elements elements in ${\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z}$ mod some irreducible. Does this pose serious cognitive issues for you? Anyway, I apologize for my rattiness but your comment was useless.

Comment: Maybe I should learn some new reading skills, because I still see in the question "field theorists use stuff like $p\in\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ for a finite field element".  I also see in your comment "polynomials with their elements elements in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$", but I see no connection between these.  In particular, I don't see what the polynomial comment has to do with the fact that elements $p$ of $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ are not finite field elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $1+4\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers $x$ such that $x$ is congruent  to $1$ modulo $4$. More familiarly, $4\mathbb{Z}$ is the ideal of all multiples of $4$.

The notation $1+4\mathbb{Z}$ is not all that far away from the old-fashioned "of the form $4k+1$."